# Filter two different dimensional array in swift

Tags: swift

I have two array like this:

```
let dataA = [[1, "CatA"], [2, "CatB"], [3, "CatC"], [4, "CatD"]]
let dataB = ["CatC", "CatA", "CatE"]
```

I am trying to get a filtered array which element is common in two arrays but compare only second value of ***dataA*** array. The result should be look like this:

```
let filteredData = ["CatC", "CatA"]
```

Comment: Sounds great! Should be relatively simple, although doing it _efficiently_ is not. May we see the code you have at this point? Thanks.

Comment: Create a set with the last elements of dataA `let setA = Set(dataA.compactMap{$0.last as? String})` then use it to filter dataB
`let filteredData = dataB.filter(setA.contains)`

Comment: `dataA` and `dataB` can have repeated values? is `dataA` ordered from 1 to * and `CatA to CatZ` ?

Comment: Leo, you should post your reply as an answer. It's a concise, performant solution, and I want to be able to upvote it!

Comment: @Claudio dataA and dataB with any arbitrary value, not in sequence.

Comment: Joya, can you be sure that the values you want to match from dataA will always be in the last position in each inner array?

Comment: Is the result order important?

Comment: @DuncanC yes brother, always last value but sequence is in **dataB** is important.

Comment: @Claudio Result order is important and should be in order with **dataB**

Comment: Leo's solution should be perfect then. It will preserve the order of items from dataB.

Comment: Is `[1, "CatA"]` meant to be that way, I mean an array? Not even a tuple, a dictionary, or better a custom struct with 2 properties? It's not related, but it might improve your code in general.

Comment: @Larme dataA and dataB with any arbitrary value, not in sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments you should structure your dataA and filter your dataB using a property of dataA. If you can not change your data structure and your dataA has unordered and arbitrary values you can compactMap its strings, flatten your collection and create a set. Then you can use it as a predicate to filter dataB:

```
let dataA = [[1, "CatA"], ["CatB", 2], ["CatC", 3], [4, "CatD"]]
let dataB = ["CatC", "CatA", "CatE"]

let setA = Set(dataA.flatMap{ elements in elements.compactMap {$0 as? String}})
let filteredData = dataB.filter(setA.contains)  // ["CatC", "CatA"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dataA = [[1, "CatA"], [2, "CatB"], [3, "CatC"], [4, "CatD"]]
let dataB = ["CatC", "CatA", "CatE"]
var filteredData: [String] = []

for data in dataA {
    if let element = data.last as? String {
        if dataB.contains(element) {
            filteredData.append(element)
        }
        
    }
}
```